# Stop objet's movement when colliding with another object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a sphere which is moving forward by transform.translate.I want my sphere to stop moving when it is colliding with another gameobject e.g A wall.I've tried many things but can't figure out the proper way.Can anyone help me with it?Thanks in advance...

Comment: What did you try? Where is your code? I mean, the current code that doesn't work. You have to put something to get something

Comment: void onCollision (Collision Collision)
 {
  GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().isKinematic = true;
  GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity = Vector3.zero;
 } Thats what I've tried.Now as I put something,if you please give me somthing.

Comment: as i said in third answer it's OnCollisionEnter not onCollision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OnCollisionEnter.Put in a script that is attached to your object.

[OncollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html)

Notes: Objects should have colliders and Collision events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a non-kinematic rigidbody attached.

Answer (score 0):

Does your sphere has a collider?

[You should read this!](http://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/detecting-collisions-oncollisionenter)

you should put more information in your question next time, like the code so we could help you out even more

Comment: void onCollision (Collision Collision)
 {
  GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().isKinematic = true;
  GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity = Vector3.zero;
 }  I've tried this but its not working.